# "In a frail voice" versus "with a frail voice"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of these are correct?

> In a frail voice, he said goodbye.
>   With a frail voice, he said goodbye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more usage than grammar; grammatically, both are correct. I'd say "in a frail voice" would be more common usage.

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct.  The first means that his voice was frail when he said goodbye, while the second means that he used a frail voice to say goodbye, so essentially they mean the same.